# Trigger script only on first instance of Form Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

Our boarding school use a Google Form for pupils to sign in and out upon arrival and departure. 
I have a function - dailyRecord() - that makes a record each night of which pupils are boarding that evening. 
There are two custom menus, one to purge the form responses at half terms and exeats (weekends out) and another that also empties the record of boarding nights for use at the end of each term.

Currently purging the form responses will also disable the dailyRecord() function (we don't want to make a record when there are no pupils in the school anyway).
I have tried to create a script that re-enables the dailyRecord() function the next time a form response is submitted (ie pupils start signing in again after the weekend/Half term). The problem is that it is running EACH time a form is submitted, meaning multiple records are being made each night instead of one. I only need the function to be re-enabled on the first form submission after the break.
Any ideas anyone

```js
//ONOPEN - Menu allowing user to choose to delete previous form submissions//
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Clear Data')
  .addItem('Exeat & HT - Purge Form reponses', 'responsesAlert')
  .addItem('End of Term - Empty History Sheets', 'historyAlert')
      .addToUi();
}

//DELETETRIGGER - Stand alone function to delete 'dailyRecord' Trigger (stop recording nightly register)// 
function deleteTrigger() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() === 'dailyRecord') {
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}
}}

//RESPONSESALERT - Alert box deleting previous form submissions 'YES', doing nothing if not//
function responsesAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
     'This will remove previous form responses - The nightly record (History Sheet) will remain intact',
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
  //Empty 'Form Responses 1' Sheet of data
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var lastRow = source.getLastRow()
  source.deleteRows(2, lastRow)}
  //Empty the Google Form of all Responses
  var form, urlForm = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl();
  if (urlForm) {}
    form = FormApp.openByUrl(urlForm);
    if (form) form.deleteAllResponses();
  //Delete 'dailyRecord' Trigger (stop recording nightly register)
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() === 'dailyRecord') {
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}
}}

//HISTORYALERT - Alert box deleting previous form submissions 'YES', doing nothing if not//
function historyAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.alert(
     'This will clear all daily records from the History Sheet',
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
  //Empty 'History' Sheet of data
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("History");
  var lastColumn = source.getLastColumn()
  source.deleteColumns(4, lastColumn-3)}
}


//DAILYTRIGGER - Trigger running record-keeping function c.10pm each night//
function dailyTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('dailyRecord')
  .timeBased()
  .atHour(22)
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();
}

//DAILYRECORD - Record-keeping function, copy/value-pasting record into next clear column//
function dailyRecord() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName('History'),
        lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn(),
        colC = ss.getRange("C:C")
            .getValues();
    ss.getRange(1, lastColumn + 1, colC.length, 1)
        .setValues(colC);
}
```

Comment: The HTML/JavaScript/CSS snippet should be used only for code that could be ran directly on this site, so I removed it. By the other hand, this looks to me like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I think that if you avoid to delete all responses from the form you will not need the dailyRecord function.

Comment: Thank you  Rubén, fairly new to this and pretty hazy on XY Problem, simply trying to share what I am trying to achieve and how I have tried to achieve it.  You are correct that not deleting form responses will help, however, with all pupils signing in and out all through the day I am concerned the spreadsheet will start to get too unwieldy. Thanks for response!

Answer (score 0):

The below code setups an onFormSubmit trigger for the firstSubmission function which is called when the form is submitted, the function deletes its own trigger essentially becoming a one time trigger or first submission trigger.

Call this function at the end of your reponseAlert function
Like this:

```
function responsesAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ....
  var form, urlForm = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl();
  if (urlForm) {}
  form = FormApp.openByUrl(urlForm);
  ....
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() === 'dailyRecord') {
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}
}
firstSubmissionTrigger(form)
}

function firstSubmissionTrigger(form){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('firstSubmission').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create()
// Sets trigger to call firstSubmission to be called when the submission is made
}

function firstSubmission(){
 dailyTrigger()
// Starts the dailyTrigger
// Below code deletes the triggers that calls firstSubmission function 
// Essentially making it a one time trigger or First submission trigger      
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
if (triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() === 'firstSubmission') {
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}

}
}
```

Comment: Really grateful for that - I'm going to implement and test it. Being a little unfamiliar with this, the 4 dots(....) just refer to the original elements remaining unchanged?

Comment: Yes I put ( ...) To refer to orginal elements remaining unchanged. So that I could hilight where I have modify the code more easily

Comment: Thank you - just started first weekend off since so made the changes - will let you know after the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments and help on this. I eventually went as simple as possible... script setup up daily trigger in the script editor and programmed script to run if more than one form entry. The form gets emptied every weekend off & half term.

```
//RECORDTRIGGER
 function recordTrigger() {
  var responses = FormApp.openByUrl('formurl.com').getResponses().length
  if (responses > 1) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('History'),
        lastColumn = ss.getLastColumn(),
        colC = ss.getRange("C:C").getValues();
    ss.getRange(1, lastColumn + 1, colC.length, 1).setValues(colC);
}}
```

Seems to work when tested - really grateful for support.